# No parser defined for Content-Type: application/json

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-api

I'm using google-http-java-client-1.10.3-beta for making RESTfull Json requests to a service provided by an external source.

I need to parse the Json that's coming in the response to build some POJOs to my app.

For that, I'm using HttpResonse method 'parse as':

```
response.parseAs(SomeModel.class)
```

But I'm getting this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No parser defined for Content-Type: application/json
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse.parseAs(HttpResponse.java:497)
```

The responded json has this format:
[{"key" : {"key" : "value", "key" : "value"}}]

I had experminted some issues with other Json libraries when handling responses with square brackets, could that be the problem here?

Any ideas?

Comment: My guess would be you are missing JSON libraries. Google-java-client comes packaged with Jackson and GSON. Make sure this libs are in your path. You can get them from this zip: http://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/downloads/detail?name=google-http-java-client-1.11.0-beta.zip&can=2&q=

Comment: Actually, I'm using gson-2.1 as suggested in the README of the zip, but thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Responding to myself, the api needs you to set manually a JsonObjectParser object to the request involved.

A JsonObjectParser might be a GsonParser or JacksonParser or any other implented parser.

So, in order to set a GsonParser to your request you could use this code:

```
HttpRequest setJsonParser(HttpRequest request) {
    JsonObjectParser parser = new JsonObjectParser(new GsonFactory());
    return request.setParser(parser);
}
```

Then you will be able to do:

```
HttpRequest request = setJsonParser(request).execute().parseAs(SomeModel.class);
```

And all your POJOs will be automatically generated.

**Note:** I've upgraded my google-http-java-client version to 1.11.0-beta, an earlier version won't return a HttpRequest object when calling setParser so be carefull when using the presented code, you may need a void instead of a function.